# WPF ItemsControl apply additional transform to items?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a custom control with a `Canvas` that manages its own "camera" which is applied to all the childs inside said `Canvas`. I tried the following:

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.CanvasControl"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
              mc:Ignorable="d"
              d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <!--This has to be the item's transform...-->
                        <MatrixTransform Matrix="{Binding Path=RenderTransform, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}} }" />
                        <!--This will be replaced with my own transform later on-->
                        <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="10" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="White" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="50" Stroke="Magenta" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="OrangeRed" />
        <Button Content="Hello world">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="-10" Y="-10"/>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        </Button>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

In this sample the `Button` should be located at `X-10;Y-10` **relative** to the `OrangeRed` `Rectangle`, however the `RenderTransform` in my `Style` seems to overridden by the `RenderTransform` in the `Button`. This makes the `Button` appear at `X-10;Y-10` **relative** to the `Canvas.`

Eventually the `ItemsControl`will have a `DataTemplateSelector` and `ItemsSource` which are configured by the user.

It seems like a simple thing to do, I must be missing something.

Comment: Why don't you simply set the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top attached properties to position the elements?

Comment: Because eventually zooming will also take place.

Comment: Why do you apply the "camera" to the individual children instead of the hosting panel? If you manipulate the view for the whole panel, most of your problems should be solved without much efford.

Comment: I already started exploring this idea myself, by setting the RenderTransform on the `Canvas`. This seems to work alright but I have to manually manage the `Canvas`' `Clip` to ensure it stays within the bounds of the `ItemsControl`

Comment: Uhm... are you talking about `<ItemsControl ClipToBounds="True" .../>`?

Comment: I learned about the existence of that a while later, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified in the comments, managing the `RenderTransform` the items panel instead of individual items mostly achieves what the question author wants.

I generally recommend to handle such transformations in a common anchestor container instead of writing more-or-less complicated math for the positioning of individual child elements.

The remaining problem was, that the items panel would grow over the boundaries of its parent control for some scaling factors. Preventing this by managing the `Panel.Clip` is just as complicated as the idea to position individual child elements.

The solution: set `ClipToBounds="True"` on the container around the items panel. This will clip everything that's going out of bounds without requiring any manual math to compute the bounds for some specific scaling.